# Change Gmail message routing on individual mailboxes

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-api, google-apps, gdata

We are using **dual delivery** for one of our Google Apps domains and need to be able to **disable** mail delivery to the Gmail account. You can manually update the settings on a per user basis through the Admin interface by unchecking the box next to "Google Apps Email" in the Email routing section.

From the [Google Apps API documentation](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/admin_settings/docs/1.0/admin_settings_developers_guide_protocol.html) for the **python** library it does not appear that I programmatically disable the email routing for "Google Apps Email" on a per user basis. Does anyone know if it's possible?

The only routing related method I can find is at the Domain level and not the user level.

gdata.apps.adminsettings.service

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you found there is no way to control the per-user routing via the APIs. You can however set and clear the user's autoforward via the Email Settings API. Note that users have access to this setting so they could potentially modify it. Also note that Google has placed restrictions on what domains can be autoforwarded to via the API (see link)

http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2010/05/gmail-now-requires-verification-of.html

Jay

Answer (score 0):

@Jay is right, however there is an [issue here](http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2293).  The more support it gets the sooner this will be available.